# C# Accessing IModelMetaDataProvider in static context - IHtmlHelper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am exploring ways of implementing a custom checkbox helper which I can use with my Razor views. The application is using `Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0`. U have tried both a custom `TagHelper` solution and a static extension method for `IHtmlHelper`.

Unfortunately, the project was originally MVC5 has a load of legacy MVC5 static  helpers which need porting.

The problematic method call is arg[2] here:

```
    ModelExplorer metadata = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, (ViewDataDictionary<TModel>)html.ViewData, [I need to resolve and pass in IModelMetadataProvider here]);
```

Here is the basic code for the helper

```
    public static IHtmlContent MvcCheckBoxFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {

        // see http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs this applies the correct "name" HTMl attribute

        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }


        // TODO: Resolve IModelMetedataProvider - argument 3 - left null 
        ModelExplorer metadata = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, (ViewDataDictionary<TModel>)html.ViewData, null);


        bool isChecked = false;
        if (metadata.Model != null)
        {
            bool modelChecked;
            if (Boolean.TryParse(metadata.Model.ToString(), out modelChecked))
            {
                isChecked = modelChecked;
            }
        }

        string fullName = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));

        return CheckBoxHelper(fullName, fullName, isChecked, htmlAttributes);
    }
```

I have omitted the `CheckBoxHelper` code as the functionality is outside the scope of the problem. Although the signature is below:

```
 private static IHtmlContent CheckBoxHelper(string name, string id, bool isChecked, object htmlAttributes)
```

The old way of achieving the call .NET 4.5.2 was:

```
 ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
```

The signature and namespace changed from `System.Web.Mvc` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal`

Just wondering what strategy I can use to make this call. MSFT's helpers such as `@Html.LabelFor` must do something under the hood - they are also in a static context.

`Activator.CreateInstance<IModelMetadataProvider>()` is available but not viable as you cannot create an instance of an interface. Is there a concrete type or workaround?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks for taking the time to read this,

John

Answer (score 4):

Just looked through the `IHtmlHelper` code - there is a IModelMetadataProvider read only field.

So,

`html.MetadataProvider`

Resolves it. I feel so silly. Many thanks MSFT for including it!

Comment: Don't feel too silly, I couldn't find an example for this anywhere.